# How do you view the percentage of people who get a Steam achievement?

Tags: steam, achievements

In the Steam Library interface, for a given game, I have a "post-game summary" section that shows an achievement, and what percentage of players obtain that achievement. (ie. "*7.2% of players have this achievement*").

[image: Steam Post-game Summary]

However, once this post-game summary disappears, I can no longer view that percentage of people. I tried going to **View My Achievements**, but it doesn't show up there.

[image]

**Question**: how do I view the percentage of players who have a specific achievement later on, after the post-game summary is gone?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can see these stats in the [Global Achievement Stats](https://steamcommunity.com/stats/FINALFANTASYVII/achievements) page, reached by clicking the "View global achievements stats" link on your achievements page:

[image: My own achievements page]

Comment: +1 for the free handle drawn ellipse

Comment: this info is also visible in the tooltip which appears in the new library view, and also in the profile box "achievement showcase"; however it's not shown in the tooltip which appears in the profile "recent activity" section, nor those which appear in the friend activity page.

Comment: I personally don't consider this the answer. As it shows all achievements, not just the achievements I've unlocked.